# Mod_rewrite simple redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpserver, ibmhttpserver

I'm totally new to IHS and I faced the problem that I need to redirect the URL of my homepage,  `www.example.com/foo --> www.example.com/foo/bar` another thing that some of the paths like `www.example.com/foo/somethingelse` are correct, I have read numerous of articles realated to mod_rewrite talking about alot more complex solutions but failed to find such simple solution like this. Also, I get really confused about that regex thing yet.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example you want requests that have the HTTP Host header set to  www.example.com
and have a URI that is just /foo or /foo/ to be redirected to www.example.com/foo/bar
The following example is a rewrite rule to achieve this

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/foo/?$ /foo/bar [R,L]
```

You can find in-depth documentation on Rewrites at the following sites:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/manual70/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/manual70/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{foo}
</IfModule>
```